# Is it possible to return the connection object from mysql function in C++ code?

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-error-1064

error: ‘sql’ does not name a type
sql::Connection connect_mysql();
Is there a way i can return the connection object from this function?
I know to return the connection object in C but not happening in C++.
edited version: return type of connect_mysql() has been changed to sql::Connection * . earlier it was sql::Connection.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<mysql/mysql.h>
#include<cppconn/driver.h>
#include<cppconn/exception.h>
#include<cppconn/resultset.h>
#include<cppconn/statement.h>
sql::Connection * connect_mysql();    


       int main()
       {
            sql::Connection *con;
            con = connect_mysql();
            return 0;
       }



      sql::Connection * connect_mysql()
        {
            cout << "CONNECTING DATABASE..............."<<endl;
            try{
                    cout<<"inside try while connecting to mysql"<<endl;
                    sql::Driver *driver;
                    sql::Connection *con;
                    sql::Statement *stmt;
                    sql::ResultSet *res;
                    driver = get_driver_instance();
                    con = driver->connect("localhost","root","Aricent@123");
                   con->setSchema( "COE" );                            
                    stmt = con->createStatement();                           
                    res = stmt->executeQuery( "show tables" );
                    while( res->next() )
                    {
                            cout<<"MYSQL replies:"<<endl;
                            cout<<res->getInt(1);
                            cout<<res->getString(1)<<endl;
                    }
           } 
        catch( exception e )
            {

                    cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;                   
                    cout << "# ERR: ";
                    cout << " (MySQL error code: ";
                    cout << ", SQLState: ";
            }
            return con;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an object, it's a pointer. Try this

```
sql::Connection* connect_mysql()
{
    ...
}
```

Another error is the lack of prototype for `connect_mysql`. You should have something like this

```
   sql::Connection* connect_mysql(); // prototype

   int main()
   {
        sql::Connection *con;
        con = connect_mysql();
        ...
```

But what is confusing me about your error message is that it refers to the line `sql::Connection* connect_mysql()` but apparently using the same type in the line `sql::Connection *con;` is OK. If you have any other error messages or warnings please post those as well.

It shouldn't need stating that for help with compiler error messages you should post the exact code, the exact error messages, and all of both of those.

I'm not an expert on mysql but I wonder if you need a header file `#include <cppconn/connection.h>`

Comment: True, but the error is more basic: `error: ‘sql’ does not name a type sql::Connection connect_mysql();`.

Comment: after making the change suggested, I am getting this error:
error: ‘sql’ does not name a type
 sql::Connection * connect_mysql();

Comment: @ShreyasBhargav You haven't used any header files in your code. That's the problem.

Comment: thats not been posted here.
the headers used are:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<mysql/mysql.h>
#include<cppconn/driver.h>
#include<cppconn/exception.h>
#include<cppconn/resultset.h>
#include<cppconn/statement.h>

Comment: I cannot see how that code would produce the error you've described. Please post the **exact** code, all of it.

Comment: @john plz refer to changes made.

Comment: @ShreyasBhargav Well another error is that you haven't prototyped your connect_mysql function. Please see my edited answer

Comment: @john well, i have added the prototype. no difference.